# how can we merge elements of an array in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to make a c++ program that merges the elements of an array For example we have three elements that are 2 5 7 and we want merge them make a number 257

Comment: How is that "merging"? That's a complete reinterpretation of numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    int a[N] = {2,5,7};

    int num = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        num = num * 10 + a[i];

    cout << num << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

steps:

> 1. num -> 0
> 2. num -> 2
> 3. num -> 25
> 4. num -> 257

Comment: this is efficient solution as log as the resulted number is not bigger than int maximum size , this should be mentioned

Comment: Didn't I just post more or less exactly that code?

Comment: The declaration of the array. but, not the algorithm.

Comment: yours is not efficient as this one.

Comment: You certainly meant `<iostream>` there.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use the range based for statement. For example

```
int a[] = { 2, 5, 7 };

int x = 0;

for ( int digit : a ) x = 10 * x + digit;
```

Here is demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 2, 5, 7 };

    int x = 0;

    for ( int digit : a ) x = 10 * x + digit;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
x = 257
```

The same can be done using standard algorithm `std::accumulate` declared in header `<algorithm>`

Take into account that the array has to have acceptable values like digits and that the resulted number would not overflow the acceptable range of values for the given type of the accumulator.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    const int N = 3; // the size of the array
    int a[N] = {2,5,7};

    // define the number that will hold our final "merged" number
    int nbr = 0;

    // loop through the array and multiply each number by the correct
    // power of ten and add it to the merged number
    for(int i=N-1;i>=0;--i){
        nbr += a[i] * pow(10, N-1-i);
    }

    // print the number
    std::cout << nbr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As for such a broad question, you should at least add some explanations what your code actually does.

Comment: Well, I just explained it. Code only answers are not applicable here.

Comment: I added some comments, better now?